# Find items in a javascript dictionary, given an array of items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object with

`values = [19, 20, 23]`

and another one with the following structure

```js
options = [{
  id = 19.0,
  label = USA
}, {
  label = Europe,
  id = 20.0
}, {
  label = Asia ex - China ex - India,
  id = 21.0
}, {
  label = China,
  id = 22.0
}, {
  label = India,
  id = 23.0
}, {
  id = 24.0,
  label = Israel
}, {
  id = 25.0,
  label = Africa
}, {
  label = Latam,
  id = 26.0
}, {
  id = 27.0,
  label = Oceania
}]
```

I need help writing a function that generates an object with the following format

`['USA', 'Europe', 'India']`

I am using right now

`value.forEach( a => options.find(b === b.id = a))`

but it is not generatign the results I want.

Comment: Starting from your input array, filter out any non-matching items, then map their labels back to an array: `options.filter(v => values.includes( v.id )).sort((a,b) => values.indexOf(a.id) - values.indexOf(b.id)).map(v => v.label);` I added a sort so the end order is the same as the order of the values.

Comment: What you need is a `filter` then a `map`.

Comment: You need to use `:` as a separator between your keys and values, not an `=`. Furthermore [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) needs a function as parameter not a comparison

Comment: [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is what you are looking for.

```js
const options = [
  {id: 19.0, label: 'USA'},
  {id: 20.0, label: 'Europe'},
  {id: 21.0, label: 'Asia ex-China ex-India'}
];

const toLookFor = [19, 20, 23];

console.log(
  options.reduce(
    (accumulator, currentValue) => {
      if(toLookFor.includes(currentValue.id)){
        accumulator.push(currentValue.label)
      };
      
      return accumulator
    },
    []
  )
);
```

Comment: It is really depending on how many lookups we need to do

Comment: @mplungjan You are correct. If I change it tho I would have to check whether the id even exists in the source and if it does not exists double in the lookup array. Also you are doing `find` in each iteration which potentially searches a larger array each time. Not sure which one is more quick in the end. But I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

the forEach method doesn't create a new array, you'll have to use map

note that your options.find method call should be a function callback.

```js
let result = values.map((a) => {
  return options.find(b => a === b.id);
})
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script>
  const values = [19, 20, 23],
    options = [{
      id: 19.0,
      "label": "USA"
    }, {
      "label": "Europe",
      id: 20.0
    }, {
      "label": "Asia ex - China ex - India",
      id: 21.0
    }, {
      "label": "China",
      id: 22.0
    }, {
      "label": "India",
      id: 23.0
    }, {
      id: 24.0,
      "label": "Israel"
    }, {
      id: 25.0,
      "label": "Africa"
    }, {
      "label": "Latam",
      id: 26.0
    }, {
      id: 27.0,
      "label": "Oceania"
    }]
</script>
```

Comment: I would go with reduce just for cases like `[19, 20, 20, 77, 23]`. But that is up to the specification.

Answer (score 1):

Filter is more elegant. Also you have IDs that are floats

```js
let result = options
  .filter(({id}) => values.includes(parseInt(id)))
  .map(({label}) => label);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script>
  const values = [19, 20, 23],
    options = [{
      id: 19.0,
      "label": "USA"
    }, {
      "label": "Europe",
      id: 20.0
    }, {
      "label": "Asia ex - China ex - India",
      id: 21.0
    }, {
      "label": "China",
      id: 22.0
    }, {
      "label": "India",
      id: 23.0
    }, {
      id: 24.0,
      "label": "Israel"
    }, {
      id: 25.0,
      "label": "Africa"
    }, {
      "label": "Latam",
      id: 26.0
    }, {
      id: 27.0,
      "label": "Oceania"
    }]
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` is a floating-point value, you would have to subtract the current value and check for floating error.

**Note:** I chose an arbitrary precision of `0.00000001` (or `1e-8`)

```js
const
  options = [
    { id: 19.0, label: 'USA' },
    { label: 'Europe', id: 20.0 },
    { label: 'Asia ex-China ex-India', id: 21.0 },
    { label: 'China', id: 22.0 },
    { label: 'India', id: 23.0 },
    { id: 24.0, label: 'Israel' },
    { id: 25.0, label: 'Africa' },
    { label: 'Latam', id: 26.0 },
    { id: 27.0, label :'Oceania' }
  ],
  values = [19, 20, 23];

const countries = options
  .filter(({ id }) => values.find(value => Math.abs(value - id) < 0.00000001))
  .map(({ label }) => label);

console.log(JSON.stringify(countries)); // [ "USA","Europe","India" ]
```

Comment: What? All numbers are of "type" floating point in javascript - 32bit signed floats. `20.0 === 20`. It's weird two notations are used but javascript couldn't care less.

Comment: @somethinghere simply err'ing [on the side of caution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger#description)

Comment: Yeah, but it's _still_ only as fool proof as the lowest precision with this method so... Slightly convoluted imho.